# Are firebase dev accounts rate-limited?

Tags: firebase

We've been developing with Firebase for a couple of months and recently we've seen some long delays in downloading data (e.g. 20 seconds).  During those times the "forge" web UI is also tremendously slow to respond.

After a while, it seems to clear up and go back to its lightning-fast self.

Could this be because I'm using a significant portion of the free quota (80 MB / 100MB of storage and 1.6 GB / GB in bandwidth)?  Are there undocumented rate limits we're hitting?

The last time this happened we had 6 concurrent users, and our alltime peak so far has been 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, dev accounts aren't rate-limited.  They're capped on connections, data storage, and monthly data transfer, but there's no rate-limiting.

If you're having performance issues, your best bet would be to email support@firebase.com detailing what you're seeing and the name of your Firebase so that we can investigate.  Typically, delays are the result of large data transfers going into or out of your Firebase (e.g. downloading your entire Firebase, which could be accidentally triggered by opening Forge) and there are usually mitigation strategies that we can help you out with.